# How are non identical cattle twins capable of transplanting each others organs?

Tags: zoology

Non identical cattle twins have different genes and by this their immunesystem works differently so initially it was suspected that eg tissue transplantation from one to the other would be rejected by the immunesystem.

Now it appears that it is possible to succeed in a organtransplantion because there body's lived in the same placenta. But how does their immunesystems get compatible with the cells of the other just through the placenta?

Comment: Can you give a source for this? Most commonly, nonidentical twins each have their own placentas, not shared placentas.

Comment: It is about cattle see: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/exd.12227/full

Comment: If your question is about cattle, please specify. Humans don't share placentas.